# How to activate a CSS animation only when hovering - without javascript

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Is there a way to get this CSS code:

```
/** Swing **/ 
.animated { 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; 
    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both; 
    animation-fill-mode: both; 
} 

@-webkit-keyframes swing { 
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100% { -webkit-transform-origin: top center; } 
    20% { -webkit-transform: rotate(15deg); } 
    40% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg); } 
    60% { -webkit-transform: rotate(5deg); } 
    80% { -webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg); } 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 
} 
@keyframes swing { 
    20% { transform: rotate(15deg); } 
    40% { transform: rotate(-10deg); } 
    60% { transform: rotate(5deg); } 
    80% { transform: rotate(-5deg); } 
    100% { transform: rotate(0deg); } 
} 

.swing { 
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center; 
    transform-origin: top center; 
    -webkit-animation-name: swing; 
    animation-name: swing; 
}


/****/
```

Generated from this website: https://coveloping.com/tools/css-animation-generator

To work only when hovering over an element? 
I added:

```
.swing:hover { 
    -webkit-transform-origin: top center; 
    transform-origin: top center; 
    -webkit-animation-name: swing; 
    animation-name: swing; 
}
```

Myself and it's not working.

Oh... And I'm trying to avoid using javascript/jQuery so the page will load faster..

Comment: Working for me in Chrome on Windows - http://jsfiddle.net/xLf427w5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/24q851ys/)

Use the `animation-play-state:running;` on `:hover`
so that it plays while hovering over.
Not hovered element should then be : `animation-play-state:paused;` so its not running without hover.

Setting the `animation-iteration-count:infinite;` makes the animation run infinite (as long as you hover in this case).